# Finding Unique Triplets Combinations to the provided Sum list

Tags: python, list, function, sum, combinations

I have series of numbers like this

```
lst = [30.25, 30.0, 19.0, 31.25, 28.25, 28.25, 29.25, 28.5, 26.5, 26.5, 25.25, 24.25, 23.75, 23.5, 20.5, 20.0, 21.75, 21.25, 21.0, 19.75, 20.0]
```

Now I want to calculate all such possible combinations whose sum is equal to a given number (target).

I have found this very powerful part of code from the fourtheye:

```
def subsets_with_sum(lst, target, with_replacement=False):
    x = 0 if with_replacement else 1
    def _a(idx, l, r, t):
        if t == sum(l): r.append(l)
        elif t < sum(l): return
        for u in range(idx, len(lst)):
            _a(u + x, l + [lst[u]], r, t)
        return r
return _a(0, [], [], target)
```

My goal is to verify if there is a combination of 3 or 4 (to be chosen before running the code) sublists with unique items from lst and to print triplet or quadruplet found.

If not: suggest 1 or 2 values to achieve the target.

PS: as you may have seen, the lst is composed by value which are decimal hours
and for my specific case my target is 168 (hours in one week)

Answer (score 0):

Use `itertools.combinations`

```
from collections import defaultdict
import itertools

lst = [30.25, 30.0, 19.0, 31.25, 28.25, 28.25, 29.25, 28.5, 26.5, 26.5, 25.25, 24.25, 23.75, 23.5, 20.5, 20.0, 21.75, 21.25, 21.0, 19.75, 20.0]

def subsets_with_sum(lst, target, ncomb, nsuggest):
    # try to get match for ncomb
    matches = [comb for comb in itertools.combinations(lst, ncomb) if sum(comb) == target]
    if matches:
        return list(set(matches))

    # suggest values
    # build up dict of target - sum(comb)
    suggestions = defaultdict(int)
    for comb in itertools.combinations(lst, ncomb - 1):
        suggestion = target - sum(comb)
        if suggestion > 0:
            suggestions[suggestion] += 1
    sorted_suggestions = sorted([(value, key) for (key,value) in suggestions.items()], reverse=True)
    return [item[1] for item in sorted_suggestions[0:ncomb]]
```

Output

```
>>>subsets_with_sum(lst, 115, 4, 2)                                                                                 
[(30.25, 30.0, 28.25, 26.5),
 (30.0, 31.25, 28.5, 25.25),
 (30.25, 31.25, 28.25, 25.25),
 (30.25, 30.0, 31.25, 23.5),
 (30.25, 31.25, 29.25, 24.25),
 (30.0, 28.25, 28.25, 28.5)]

>>>subsets_with_sum(lst, target=215, ncomb=4, nsuggest=2)                                                                                 
[140.25, 138.5]
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your fast answer! it really help me! I may have not well explained but in your case there are 6 ncomb and i want to restrict it to 3 or 4, and the numbers of items are restricted to 4 in my case i don't want to restrict it. finaly the suggestion have to be between 32 and 18 hours and the values in each sublist have to be unique ant used in an other sublist